# Creating a for loop for an enumerate environment that will take the number of items, and what the items say

Tags: enumerate, loops

I know how to put \foreach loops into tikz code, but that isn't super helpful here. I'm building a rubric and I'd like to be able to say "there are this many items in the rubric and the first one should say ..., the second one..., etc." Here's what i have currently:

```
    \newcommand{\rubricTwo}[2]
    {\vspace{3mm}
    \begin{enumerate}[label = ]
    \item \line(1,0){25} \ /1 \ #1
    \item \line(1,0){25} \ /1 \ #2
    \end{enumerate}}
```

I'd like it to do something like this where \ItemNumber is the number of items to enumerate and \RubricItems is a list of what each item says.

```
    \newcommand{\rubric}[\ItemNumber][\RubricItems]
    {\vspace{3mm}
    \begin{enumerate}[label = ]
    \item \line(1,0){25} \ /1 \ #1 (first RubricItem)
    \item \line(1,0){25} \ /1 \ #2 (second RubricItem)
    .
    .
    \item \line(1,0){25} \ /1 \ \ItemNumber (last RubricItem)
    \end{enumerate}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not what you want, but something close can be achieved with `\foreach`

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\foreach \ItemNumber/\RubricItem in { 1/bla, 2/blabla, 3/blablabla}{
\item \line(1,0){25} \ /1 \ \ItemNumber \ \RubricItem
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]